# How to solve " django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "Oeloun-pc" " in Pycharm Windows?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Below is my screenshot of PyCharm including settings.py and pg_hba.conf file.

PyCharm with pg_hba.conf screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
'USER': 'admin',
```

instead of

```
'USERNAME': 'admin',
```